# how to extract json from a string?

Tags: python, json, post

a POST request comes to my server in string format, are there any simple methods for converting to JSON format, for further work with data?

```
import json

file = "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 11.112.19.113:5111\r\nUser-Agent: Yandex.Forms/1.0\r\nContent-Length: 187\r\nAccept: */*\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nX-Delivery-Id: 139195725\r\nX-Form-Answer-Id: 1278204217\r\nX-Form-Id: 63976cbbc09c022dcd6a47e3\r\n\r\n{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"method\": \"\", \"params\": {\"message\": \"{\\\"\\u0421\\u043e\\u043e\\u0431\\u0449\\u0435\\u043d\\u0438\\u0435\\\": \\\"my test message\\\"}\", \"email\": \"jjrkl@yandex.ru\"}, \"id\": \"139195725\"}"
filename = 'test.json'

data = file.split("\n")
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
```

Comment: In an HTTP request, headers are separated from the body with *two line breaks: `\r\n\r\n`*. Just split by that, then you have raw JSON, which you can decode.

Comment: Why are you processing the raw HTTP header and data yourself? Why not use a library like Flask?